# How to in MySQL order rows by number of matches in associative table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I apologize, because I really didn't know how to correctly form my question, so I will explain my problem:

I have 3 simple MySQL tables:

- table `recipes` with column `id` and many others which are not important for this problem
- table `ingredients` with 2 columns: `id`, `name`
- associative table `recipes_ingredients` with 2 ID columns `id_recipes` and `id_ingredients`

Now I want user to search for recipes by their ingredients. User can specify one or more ingredients at a time. I know how to write SQL for the case when I want recipes that match ALL user's ingredients or recipes that match AT LEAST ONE of the ingredients.

But my question is, how do I get recipes ordered so that the first one is the one with most ingredients matching ingredients searched for by user.

I have been thinking about this all day but I have not come up with any ideas. Thanks for any help or hints in advance.

**EDIT:** My condition for the SQL query is, that I want all the recipes that have AT LEAST one ingredient in `recipes_ingredients` table, but I want those matching recipes ordered by number of matches of searched ingredients.

For example: User searches for 3 ingredients. There are 10 recipes that have at least one of these ingredients present. But I want to sort them, so first recipe would be the one that possibly matches all 3 searched ingredients. Then would be recipes that match only 2 ingredients and last will be recipes with only one matching ingredient.

Comment: What do you mean 'most match'? Do all result recipes should have _all_ input ingredients or not? Some table data also would be very helpful.

Comment: See for instance http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=90 or (closely related) http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,507748,507839#msg-507839

Comment: can you provide some sample data, a sample of what you would search for, and what you expect the results to be?

Comment: I suspect you need then 1 else 0

Comment: OK, I will edit my question to make it more clear, hang on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unverified:

```
select r.id, count(i.id) as ing_cnt 
from recipes r
left join recipes_ingredients ri on ri.id_recipes = r.id
left join ingredients i on ri.id_ingredients = i.id
group by r.id
order by ing_cnt desc
```

Comment: @juergen d: looks promising, I will test it out and let know how it works.